# How to use mongodb functions with mongoimport?

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

Let's say I want to insert an object that contains date objects using mongoimport from the commandline.

```
echo "{\"int_key\": 1, \"date_key\": new Date(\"2022-12-27\")}" | mongoimport --host "192.168.60.10" --db example_db --collection example_collection
```

will not work because the object I am trying to insert is not in the form of a valid JSON. The reason I want to use mongoimport is because there is an array of a large number of objects that I want to persist at one go. If I try to use the `mongo` command the argument length for `--eval` is too long. For example,

```
mongo --host "192.168.60.10" --eval "db=db.getSiblingDB(\"example_db\");db.getCollection(\"example_collection\").insert([{\"int_key\": 1, \"date_key\": new Date(\"2022-12-27\")}])"
```

but the array inside `insert()` has a very large number of objects. Can you suggest any workaround to this? I was thinking I could use `mongoimport` to read all the objects put into an array through stdin or a file. The options for using a json array would not allow the kind of array of objects I insert using the `insert()` in `mongo --eval`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this

```
echo "{\"int_key\": 1, \"date_key\": {\"$date\": \"2022-12-27\"}}"
```

It may require:

```
echo "{\"int_key\": 1, \"date_key\": {\"\$date\": \"2022-12-27T00:00:00Z\"}}"
```

For other data types see [MongoDB Extended JSON (v2)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/)

I use `mongoimport` in the same way to insert around 6 billion documents per day, it is very fast and reliable.

Depending on how you use it, [mongoimport does not import small amount of documents](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-2766) could be relevant for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. ```echo "{\"int_key\": 1, \"date_key\": {\"\$date\": \"2022-12-27T00:00:00Z\"}}"``` works but using just ```2022-12-27``` resulted in ```Failed: invalid $date value string: 2022-12-27```

Comment: Would you know how I can use the equivalent of new Date() in an extended json? Something like ```echo "{\"int_key\": 1, \"date_key\": {\"\$date\": \"new Date()\"}}"```

Comment: Use the shell function, e.g. : `echo "{ \"date_key\": {\"\$date\": {\"\$numberLong\": \"$(date '+%s')000\"}} }"` or `$(date -u '+%FT%TZ')`